# square shape won't disappear when clicked on

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why my shape won't disappear when it is clicked. I am almost certain I wrote the correct code down for a disappearing function. I wrote a code that displays a green square and it should disappear when it is clicked but does not. Here it is:

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <title>Javascript</title>       
        <style type="text/css">     
        #shape{     
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:green;     
        }       
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>  
    <div id ="shape">
    oo  
    </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript">     
        var start=new Date().getTime();     
        document.getElementById("shape").onclick=function(){        
        document.getElementbyId("shape").style.display="none";      
        var end=new Date().getTime();       
        var time=end-start;
        alert(time);
        }
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

I think it has something to do with my browser

Answer (score 0):

Your `document.getElementbyId("shape").style.display="none";` on line 38 has to be changed to
`document.getElementById("shape").style.display="none";`

You have could see this error in your browser JS-console.

`Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code and it may help....

```
var start = new Date().getTime();     
$("#shape").click(function(){     
  document.getElementById("shape").style.display="none"; 
  var end=new Date().getTime();       
  var time=end-start;
  alert(time);
});
```

Comment: JavaScript it case sensitive getElementbyId is differ from getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from  "getElementbyId" to "getElementById"